# Extract the Methods used in Android Java Source Code

Tags: java, android, parsing

I have been trying to get the methods used in the .java file of an Android Application for my project. I have used parser that are available on internet but they parse out only the user defined methods or the core java methods. I would like to extract the methods that are also part of android framework just like how eclipse shows the list of methods and variables in the Java outline tab.

I have tried using javaparser, AST Parser and Java API java.lang.reflect.Method. For example, if I have a java file like following

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.portrait_only)) {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        } else {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        }
    }

    public void showLogin() {
        registerNumberEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        passwordEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        loginButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        textView1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        txtProg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        loginStat = true;
    }
}
```

For the above code I need the list of methods and parameters used in the code like

```
Methods:
     OnCreate
     getResources
     getBoolean
     setRequestedOrientation
     showLogin
     setVisibility
```

but not

```
Methods:
    showLogin
```

Thank you for helping me out...

Answer (score 2):

I think java reflection API works fine in this case, Please try below code :

```
for (Method m:MainActivity.class.getMethods()){
        System.out.println(m.getName());
    }
```

Comment: thanks that was pretty much what I was expecting. I was trying getDeclaredMethods() all along....